# Component cannot listen to react-router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-v4

I have a component that is used persistently across my spa. I want it to be aware of my router and the various paths that my spa is on. Is there an easy way to do this, or do I have to bandaid some redux (or something similar) state solution that is always listening to my router changes? Thanks! You can see the below for an example.

**index.jsx:**

```
import 'babel-polyfill';
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { ConnectedRouter } from 'connected-react-router';
import { Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import { history, store } from './redux/store';
import Navigation from './navigation';

const UserReport = () => <h2>User Report</h2>;

const UserPage = () => <h2>User Page</h2>;

const Routes = () => (
  <React.Fragment>
    <Route component={Navigation} />
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/users/:startDate" component={UserReport} />
      <Route exact path="/users/:userId" component={UserPage} />
    </Switch>
  </React.Fragment>
);

render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
      <Routes />
    </ConnectedRouter>
  </Provider>, document.getElementById('app'),
);
```

**navigation.jsx:**

```
import React from 'react';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

const Navigation = (props) => {
  console.log(props.match.path);
  // expected: "/users/:startDate"
  // received: "/"
  return (
    <h2>Navigation</h2>
  );
};

export default withRouter(Navigation);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[I ended up using this react-router github discussion as my solution](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/5947).

An example of my implementation:

**index.jsx:**

```
import 'babel-polyfill';
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { ConnectedRouter } from 'connected-react-router';
import { Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import { history, store } from './redux/store';
import Layout from './layout';

const home = () => <h2>Home Page</h2>;
const users = () => <h2>Users</h2>;
const userPage = () => <h2>User Page</h2>;

const layoutRender = component => route => <Layout component={component} route={route} />;

const Routes = () => (
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/" component={layoutRender(home)} />
    <Route exact path="/users" component={layoutRender(users)} />
    <Route exact path="/users/:id" component={layoutRender(userPage)} />
  </Switch>
);

render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
      <Routes />
    </ConnectedRouter>
  </Provider>, document.getElementById('app'),
);
```

**layout.jsx:**

```
import React from 'react';

const Layout = (props) => {
  const {
    component: Component,
    route,
  } = props;

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>This is the layout</h1>
      <Component route={route} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Layout;
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the `Navigation` route doesn't have any path specified, it always matches whatever path you're on but the `match.path` only shows you the minimum path required to match for the navigation. That's why it's always `/`.

You can use `location.pathname` but it gives you the matched value and not the matched path.

```
const Navigation = props => {
  console.log(props.location.pathname);
  // prints `/users/1` if you're on https://blah.com/users/1
  // prints `/users/hey` if you're on https://blah.com/users/hey
  return <h2>Navigation</h2>;
};
```

Not sure that's what you want but if you expand what exactly you're trying to achieve, maybe I can help more.

Moreover, your second route to `path="/users/:userId"` overshadows the first route. Meaning there is no way to tell if `hey` in `/users/hey` is `startDate` or `userId`. You should introduce a separate route like `path="/users/page/:userId"`.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately, I'm needing to know the path parameter. That is, `/users/:userId`, and not `/users/1`.

Comment: @Jimmy, can you tell me what your use-case is?

Comment: I'm writing a react spa with a notifications modal that is persistent across the spa, just like how the `Navigation` component is. The Notifications modal needs to know the current page that the user is on, and based on that page, conditionally render different information.

Comment: @Jimmy, why not duplicating the routes in your navigation?

Comment: Can you clarify?

Comment: @Jimmy, you are conditionally rendering different components based on the route in your `<Switch>`. Add a `Switch` in your `Navigation` and add the same routes, then under each route render your notifications.

Comment: Unfortunately I am not. The same notification modal is always being persistently rendered and needs to be.